# Does upsert match on both id and partionKey or only id in cosmosdb?

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

### Some background information

I have a Cosmos database using the sql api. In here I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "city": "myCity",
    "address": "myAddress"
}
```

`id` is used for the id and `city` is used for partitionKey.

Suppose I do an Upsert and pass the object below as the payload and the value `"myCity"` as the partitionKey, will it insert a new document or will it  update the already existing one?

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "city": "anotherCity",
    "address": "myAddress"
}
```

In .net the Upsert could look something like this

```
await myRepository.UpsertItemAsync(myObject, "myCity");
```

### The question

Does an Upsert into a CosmosDB container only have to match on ID or does it have to match on both ID and PartitionKey do perform an Update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does an Upsert into a CosmosDB container only have to match on ID or
> does it have to match on both ID and PartitionKey do perform an
> Update?

It will have to match both Id and PartitionKey to perform an update. Combination of Id and PartitionKey is a unique identifier for a document in a Cosmos DB container.